# 2 Row Ribbon Cable Connector Pin Swap

Tags: cables, adapter

I have two different LCD displays that uses a 2 row, 16 pin connectors.  For reasons unknown, one of the designs has customized the connection and implemented a pin swap that makes using an off the shelf LCD display very difficult.  I am looking for an adapter to swap pin 1 for 2, 3 for 4, etc. on one end of the cable.  We are currently slitting the ribbon cable into 2 wire pairs, 1/2 twisting each pair and attaching them to the ribbon cable.  While this works, it is error prone and time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Would this trick help you?

It swaps odd vs. even pins.

[image: Odd Even Pin Swap]

Comment: It sounds like exactly what we are looking for.  Where would I find a copy to evaluate.

Comment: This is made from standard IDC connectors and a simple pin header with long pins, nothing special about it.